# More than one condition in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble in C# my code has to detect that every **pictureBox has same image then do a process.** But my code is not running properly. ***I'm using .Net Framework 4.8 and WinForms.***

**Event: Button1_Click**

Code:

```
            string Location = Application.StartupPath.ToString();
            if (pictureBox1.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.tick &&
                pictureBox2.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.tick &&
                pictureBox3.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.tick &&
                pictureBox4.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.tick &&
                pictureBox5.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.tick)
            {
                if (File.Exists(Location + "\\files\\e.etf"))
                {
                    File.Delete(Location + "\\files\\e.etf");
                }
                if (File.Exists(Location + "\\files\\n.etf"))
                {
                    File.Delete(Location + "\\files\\n.etf");
                }
                if (File.Exists(Location + "\\files\\p.etf"))
                {
                    File.Delete(Location + "\\files\\p.etf");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
```

But whenever *I click the butto*n it always shows the **MessageBox showing "Error".** Please help me.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `Resources` is a factory.  It creates a new object each time so a) that little snippet is creating a lot of images that are never disposed and b) a newly created object can never, ever equal an older one.  Cache the image in a variable (or array if there are a lot of them) and compare and assign from there

Comment: Not that it matters here, however: use [**&&** for logical AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators). It is the operator intended for this use and is short-circuiting. Using “bool & bool” should be done vary sparingly, such as when all expressions must be evaluated or in other highly specialized code.

Comment: @user2864740 I have used && but it is also not working. 

Comment: I'm disposing pictureBox BackgroundImage but create a new one. But the problem still remains the smae.

Comment: You can't do this `pictureBox1.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.tick` for several reasons. One is that __the Image or BackgroundImage can't be compared__ to any other bitmap. Instead you should store the name or an ID when load these images! - (They are __reference variables__ and they all will always have a different reference/address)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Remember that images cannot be compared in this way.

You can pass some variable like some bool for each picturebox and set it to true whenever the picurebox gets tick image.

Then change your if condition to comparing if all bools are true.

You are ready to go!

> Remember that this is the easiest way. There can be other ways too!

Comment: A common way to store such information like a flag or a name etc is the Tag property each control has.

Comment: @TaW: Yes. However, this is easier for novices.

Comment: _this_ ??? What is? You didn't show any code, just wrote _You can pass some variable_ Rather unclear.

Comment: @TaW; It is quite **hard** to write any code for custom demands. I don't know his code, I don't know much of his project. All I can do is provide some idea. But still, I will try to create a method and add it to the answer.

Comment: Actually is is next to impossible to write code or even properly answer a question that is being changed. It latest version makes even laess than the first one.. - Imo out combined advice is all it deserves..